# How to write/read video media files to/from mediastorage android?

Tags: android, video, mediastore, ipfs

I am working with IPFS on android. I could fetch a video from IPFS which is stored in byte[].
I want to save it to mediastorage.

I checked everywhere, I couldn't find any source which could help properly to write the video into mediastore.

Please give me suggesstions, regarding that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediastore